# Mysql Update Set Max Values

Tags: mysql

I would like to update mysql. Here is the query

```
UPDATE citizen_data SET energy=energy+?,hunger=hunger+?,thirsty=thirsty+?,mood=mood+? WHERE username=?
```

The problem is

- Energy should not more than 100, for example if we have 90 energy then we add 20. It would be 110. The energy should not exceed 100 for sure. So, how do I set it into 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `LEAST()` scalar function here:

```
UPDATE citizen_data
SET energy = LEAST(energy + 20, 100)
-- other set criteria here...
```

Here we take the *smaller* of `energy + 20` or `100`.  For energy values such that adding 20 would result in a value over 100, we update with 100, otherwise we update with that sum.

Comment: Been searching in mysql document for 3 hours did not find any answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @BobbyJulian You could also use a more brute force `CASE` expression: `SET energy = CASE WHEN energy + 20 > 100 THEN 100 ELSE energy + 20 END` ... but I prefer using `LEAST()`, which is available on MySQL.